# Symfony2 append hash fragment parameters to the pagination URL

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator

I'm developing a website using `symfony2`. I'm using the [KnpPaginationBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to paginate the list of products in my page.
Every thing is working just fine.
But I couldn't find a way to pass an additional parameters like the id of the div section I want to display in the website url something like: `localhost/my_store/web/app_dev.php/products?page=2#idsection`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to achieve your goal and both of them are connected with javascript.

1) If you have url localhost/website/app_dev.php/page=2#blockid you could try to get this id from url and scroll down by js.
Your js should be smth like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ourUrl = window.location.href; 
  var pattern = /#\w+$/;
  var divId = ourUrl.match(pattern));
  var offset = $(divId).offset();
  window.scrollTo(0, offset.top);
});
```

2)Another way is to paginate products with ajax. With this approach your won't need to scroll somewhere.

Comment: Actually I just want that when I go to the next page I reload the page and then display the section where I have the list of my products. I don't think that I need to pass it as a query parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I think i don't completely understand you problem... You have a list of products and you use bundle to paginate them. You say "go to the Next Page". Is this a pagination page, or another website's page? You want to set an id of some div where the list should be displayed?

Comment: yes exactly in the same pagination page I want that when the page is reloading it display the section mentioned with the hash fragment

Comment: Ok, and what is "section"? Is it some div that could be any div on the page? And you want to display it inside your pagination div? Or it is a part of your product list. Expected result is not clear for me. What is the difference between your expectations and the result of Pagination Bundle's work results?

Comment: Maybe you want to store the pagination results after page reload ? To achieve this you could use session

Comment: ok I'll explain it, I have for example in the bottom of the body : `<div id="section_id">something</div>` when I paginate I get the url: `mywebsite/page=2` so I reload the whole page and I display the page from the top of the body content. But when we use  the url: `mywebsite/page=2#section_id` we reload the page and go down directly to the div with the specified id .

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but in the event anyone else is looking for the capability to have fragments in their knp/paginator-bundle URIs.

The Symfony 3.2+ `UrlGenerator` accepts the [`_fragment` parameter](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements) that is used to create the `#` fragment.

In knp/paginator-bundle, the `$paginator->paginate()` interface provides the `SlidingPagination::setParam()` method which is passed to the Symfony `UrlGenerator`.

```
UrlGenerator::generate($pagination->getRoute(), $pagination->getParams())
```

In knp/paginatior-bundle 2.0 - 2.2.* the [`SlidingPagination::sortable()`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/v2.2/Pagination/SlidingPagination.php#L133) method calls the `UrlGenerator::generate()` method.

In knp/paginatior-bundle 2.3.* the [knp_pagination_* twig functions](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/v2.3/Twig/Extension/PaginationExtension.php#L127) calls the `UrlGenerator::generate()` method.

In knp/paginatior-bundle 2.4+ the router logic was moved from the Twig Extension to the [Processor](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/v2.8.0/Helper/Processor.php#L134).

**Example Usage**

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), $limit);
$pagination->setParam('_fragment', 'idsection');

return $this->render('view.html.twig', [
    'pagination' => $pagination
]);
```

```
{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Title', 'alias.property') }} #idsection

{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }} #idsection
```